# Getting values from multiple google worksheets using single "gspread" command

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, attributeerror, gspread

I've been writing this code to access a google sheet named "Classmates" and two worksheets within it named, "School" and "Collage" each with file handle "ws1" and "ws2".

```
import gspread
jf=gspread.service_account("E:\PyProj\Gsheets\creds.json")
wb=jf.open("Classmates")
ws1=wb.worksheet("School")
ws2=wb.worksheet("Collage")

inp=int(input("What data you want to get\t:"))
if inp==1:
    ws="ws1"
elif inp==2:
    ws="ws2"
else:
    print("Try again")
data=ws.get_all_values()        #line 14 with error
print(data)
```

Now I'm trying to get_all_values from either of the two sheet depending upon the choice.
It is giving the following error

```
line 14, in <module>
data=ws.get_all_values()

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_all_values'
```

I dont want to write separate code to get values .
Since I'm using Gspread so please suggest solution from Gspread API reference rather than Google Sheets API.
Thank You

Comment: At the point where you get the error, ws is a string and therefore doesn't have an attribute called get_all_values. 

Change ws="ws1" to ws=ws1 and ws="ws2" to ws=ws2

Answer (score 1):

Well I tried a work around and it worked

```
import gspread
jf=gspread.service_account("E:\PyProj\Gsheets\creds.json")
wb=jf.open("Classmates")
def getvalue(sheetname):
    ws1=wb.worksheet(sheetname)
    lis_of_name=ws1.get_all_values()
    return lis_of_name
    
inp=int(input("What data you want to get\t:"))
if inp==1:
    data=getvalue("School")
elif inp==2:
    data=getvalue("Collage")
else:
    print("Try again")
print("BACK IN MAIN :-)")
print(data)
```

There rather than saving the file handle name in "ws", I send the name of sheet as argument for worksheet().